# How to check valid numeric in number for a given length?

Tags: cobol

How to check 12-digit id-number is numeric or not numeric, if my id is  with 10 digits but my field is 12 digit numeric how to check valid 12 digit id-number in COBOL?

Comment: Can you provide some code to show us how far you got?

Comment: If input-id is numeric then move input-id to output-id   but it check only numeric if input-id is less than 12 digits then how to proceed

Comment: Add the code, including the data definitions, to your question, please.

Comment: 01 input-id pic 9(12). if input-id is only 10 digits entered then also complier accept as numeric but i need 12 digit-number with valid.

Comment: Thanks. This needs to go into the question, use the `edit` link under the question. Also need to see the code for how the data gets in there, and the compiler/OS would be useful as well.

Comment: if input-id is numeric ... if input-id > 99999999999 .... valid!

Comment: @MrSimpleMind `001234567890` is not valid?

Comment: @lurker no it not valid, from what I understand from WhiteyNag's could be that I misunderstand the question though

Comment: In Cobol a field is numeric, if all 12 digits are numeric. If you have deffinition 01  field   pic 9(12) and and the value is '  1234567890' or '1234567890  ' - for Cobol the field is NOTnumeric.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some demo code, and output.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. CHECKNUMB.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 INPUT-ID PIC 9(12).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    MOVE 'abc' TO INPUT-ID
    PERFORM CHECK-CORRECT-12-NUMB

    MOVE 001234567890 TO INPUT-ID
    PERFORM CHECK-CORRECT-12-NUMB

    MOVE 1234567890 TO INPUT-ID
    PERFORM CHECK-CORRECT-12-NUMB

    MOVE 12345678901 TO INPUT-ID
    PERFORM CHECK-CORRECT-12-NUMB

    MOVE 123456789012 TO INPUT-ID
    PERFORM CHECK-CORRECT-12-NUMB

    GOBACK.

CHECK-CORRECT-12-NUMB SECTION.
    DISPLAY 'checking input: ' INPUT-ID
    IF INPUT-ID IS NUMERIC
        DISPLAY 'is numeric'
        IF INPUT-ID > 99999999999 
            DISPLAY 'correct! 12 digits entered!'
        ELSE
            DISPLAY 'expected 12 digits!'
        END-IF
    ELSE
        DISPLAY 'non numeric entered'
    END-IF
    DISPLAY '-------'
    CONTINUE.
```

**Output**

```
checking input: 000000000abc                                                  
non numeric entered                                                           
-------                                                                       
checking input: 001234567890                                                  
is numeric                                                                    
expected 12 digits!                                                           
-------                                                                       
checking input: 001234567890                                                  
is numeric                                                                    
expected 12 digits!                                                           
-------                                                                       
checking input: 012345678901                                                  
is numeric                                                                    
expected 12 digits!                                                           
-------                                                                       
checking input: 123456789012                                                  
is numeric                                                                    
correct! 12 digits entered!                                                   
-------
```